# Filter users on 'officeLocation' in Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm working with the Microsoft Graph API and what I'm trying to achieve is to import all the people in my office location from Azure AD into my personal contacts.

Using the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) I can find myself in `/users/` using `$filter` - so using `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=mail eq '<MyEmailAddress>'`. See the results below:

[image]

So this user (me) has a property `officeLocation` which is the propery I would like to filter on in order to get all my colleagues in the same office. Therefore I tried:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=officeLocation eq '<MyOfficeLocation>'`

However - I get a `Request_UnsupportedQuery` error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
        "message": "Unsupported or invalid query filter clause specified for property 'officeLocation' of resource 'User'.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "407d5376-eeb4-46a5-8c93-c20e5b6b322e",
            "date": "2017-07-13T15:26:49"
        }
    }
}
```

Does this mean that I'm not allowed to filter on this property? That would be rather unfortunate. If so - any workarounds I can apply?

Answer (score 1):

It works like this with $count, even including $expand and $select clauses:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$top=999&$count=true&$filter=startswith(officeLocation,'EU_')&$select=id,displayName&$expand=manager($select=id,mail,displayName;$levels=1)
ConsistencyLevel: eventual
```

Here, I'm querying users' id, displayName and some details of their 1st level manager (id, mail, displayName) where the user's officeLocation starts with 'EU_'

And you must send *ConsistencyLevel: eventual* in the request header for it to work..

[image: graph api screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that is currently the case. You could filter on city and/or state maybe instead? If this is something you need please create a user voice feature request here (and be sure to include your scenario):  https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/101632-microsoft-graph-o365-rest-apis

Hope this helps,

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for your response. There is no `city` or `state` property shown when I call the `/users/` endpoint ( see image ). Does that mean the property does not exist on the user entity, or is it just not shown?

Comment: Hi Jochen, you can use https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=city (the city and state properties exist, but are not returned as a part of the default set. Per the description at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list , you need to use the $select query parameter.